# Iterator remove method

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, byte, removeclass

I have a code from example, but it is not working:

```
List<Byte> myList = Arrays.asList(B);
Iterator<Byte> itr = myList.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())  
{  
    Byte element = itr.next();  
    if(element == 32)  
    {  
        itr.remove();  
    }  
}
```

I am not able to understand why the above code is generating the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:144)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:360)
```

Comment: Because that's exactly what the docs say it will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(B);` returns a fixed-size list: you can set or get items but not remove or add. This is explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

To create a list with flexible size, you can use:

```
List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<> (B.length);
Collections.addAll(myList, B);
```

which is more efficient (only one object creation) than and as readable as:

```
List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(B));
```

Comment: How to create list which can be modified?
I have array of Byte[] B = new Byte[];

Comment: Do I need to put <Byte> in brackets?                          List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<BYTE> (Arrays.asList(B));

Comment: Yes with Java 6, no with Java 7 or higher.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Byte> myList = Arrays.asList(B);
```

returns a fixed size list that cannot be modified.

Comment: How to create list which can be modified?

Comment: I have array of Byte[] B = new Byte[];

Comment: List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(B));

Comment: Thank you! Could u tell me Do I need to put <Byte> in brackets? List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<BYTE> (Arrays.asList(B));

Comment: That depends on your JDK level. If you are using JDK below 1.7, it is mandatory to use type in 'DIAMOND' operator.

Comment: OK, thank you, it shows me error, that's why I need to use <Byte>

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` returns `Arrays.ArrayList` which is static inner class and does not override the remove operartion of `AbstractList`  and the [default remove operation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.remove%28int%29) of `AbstractList` throws  `UnsupportedOperationException`.

[Find the openjdk code for `Arrays.ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList).

Comment: I have array of Byte[] B = new Byte[]; I need to convert it to List  How to create list which can be modified?

Comment: List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(B));

Comment: Do I need to put <Byte> in brackets? List<Byte> myList = new ArrayList<BYTE> (Arrays.asList(B));